# comparing identical strings returns false

Tags: php, string, encryption, comparison, string-length

I have 2 tables a merchant table and order table. each table has a secret key I use to compare to check security. Both are encrypted. I decrypt them to validate. The problem is after decryption I get the same string value but comparing them returns false. Here's the code

THIS ISSUE HAPPENS IF STRING HAS SPECIAL CHARACTERS AND DOESN'T HAPPEN IF STRING HAS LETTERS AND NUMBERS ONLY

```
public function merchant_encrypt($pure_string, $encryption_key) {
    $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
    $encrypted_string = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, $encryption_key, utf8_encode($pure_string), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
    return $encrypted_string;
}

public function merchant_decrypt($encrypted_string, $encryption_key) {
    $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
    $decrypted_string = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, $encryption_key, $encrypted_string, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
    return $decrypted_string;
}

public function replace_spechial_charater($value){
    $value = str_replace('+=','plusequal',$value);
    $value = str_replace('=','equalsign',$value);
    $value = str_replace('+','plussign',$value);
    $value = str_replace('/','slashsign',$value);
    $value = str_replace('&','andsign',$value);
    return $value;
}

public function restore_spechial_charater($value){
    $value = str_replace('plusequal','+=',$value);
    $value = str_replace('equalsign','=',$value);
    $value = str_replace('plussign','+',$value);
    $value = str_replace('slashsign','/',$value);
    $value = str_replace('andsign','&',$value);
    return $value;
}

public function strhex($string) { 
    $hexstr = unpack('H*', $string); 
    return array_shift($hexstr); 
}
```

Saving the merchant key

```
$enc_key = $row['merchant_id'];
$merchant_key = trim($_POST['key']); //e.g: 1234abcd+=&$
$merchant_key = replace_spechial_charater($merchant_key);
$encrypted_key = merchant_encrypt($merchant_key ,$enc_key);
$encrypted_key = base64_encode($encrypted_key);
//save $encrypted_key in the merchant table
```

To decrypt it

```
$decrypted_key = base64_decode($row['key']);
$decrypted_key = decrypt($decrypted_key,$row['merchant_id']);
$decrypted_key = restore_spechial_charater($decrypted_key);
// the result is 2d1d54rt5h4th5rh5tr1h%$&^/+=gdgdfgd
```

The same non-encrypted key is encrypted in the merchant website but with another enc_key

```
$enc_key = $row['order_id'];
$merchant_key = $row['key']; // 1234abcd+=&$
$merchant_key = replace_spechial_charater($merchant_key);
$encrypted_key = merchant_encrypt($merchant_key ,$enc_key);
$encrypted_key = base64_encode($encrypted_key);
//send $encrypted_key with other parameters to the payment gateway then returned to the php script

$order_decrypted_key = base64_decode($row['order_id']);
$order_decrypted_key = decrypt($order_decrypted_key ,$row['order_id']);
$order_decrypted_key = restore_spechial_charater($order_decrypted_key );
// the result is 2d1d54rt5h4th5rh5tr1h%$&^/+=gdgdfgd

var_dump(strip_tags($decrypted_key));
var_dump(strip_tags($order_decrypted_key));
$result = strcasecmp( trim($decrypted_key), trim($order_decrypted_key) );
echo $result;
//var_dump(trim()) returns the same result for both values
```

The result is:

```
string(39) "2d1d54rt5h4th5rh5tr1h%$&^/+=gdgdfgd" 
string(35) "2d1d54rt5h4th5rh5tr1h%$&^/+=gdgdfgd" 
3
```

Then:

```
$order_key = strhex($order_decrypted_key);
$merchant_key = strhex($decrypted_key);

var_dump(trim($decrypted_key));
var_dump(trim($order_decrypted_key));
```

string(78)

```
"326431643534727435683474683572683574723168252426616d703b5e2f2b3d67646764666764"
```

string(70)

```
"3264316435347274356834746835726835747231682524265e2f2b3d67646764666764"
```

So how to fix this issue and check if they are equal or not

Comment: So a string length of 39 bytes and a string length of 35 bytes are identical??? I'd guess null bytes for padding

Comment: As you can see on the var dumps, the strings are not equal. You should have some hidden characters inside the first string. Also, you do not need to echo the var dump. Only calling var_dump() is enough. We need more details on your decryption function itself to further details on the hidden characters.

Comment: I know length is not identical but they are identical in strings how can I make them identical as they are the same value I used

Comment: if it were null bytes for padding, trim would take care of them. without knowing more about how were the strings formed, difficult to say. At the very worst I'd loop those strings to see the character code of each of the characters, to try to see what non-printable characters are coming through.

Comment: `var_dump(trim($yourstrings))` gives you the same result?

Comment: @yivi : yes the same result

Comment: @LukasMeine : Code updated with encryption function

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you run `strip_tags` for that echo?

Comment: @yivi : It was an answer for a similar question I tried it but didn't solve my problem

Comment: Use `function strhex($string) {
  $hexstr = unpack('H*', $string);
  return array_shift($hexstr);
}` to convert the strings to ASCII hex values, and match those up to the displayed characters

Comment: @MarkBaker : Code updated with the strhex function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two strings aren't the same, as everyone gathered. And there is no mystery padding I'm afraid.

Your longer string is `2d1d54rt5h4th5rh5tr1h%$&amp;^/+=gdgdfgd`
(notice the htmlentity in the middle, accounting for the 4 extra characters).

(Found by running the following on your unpacked data):

```
$string = "326431643534727435683474683572683574723168252426616d703b5e2f2b3d67646764666764";
$packed = pack("H*", $string);
var_dump($packed);
```

Response:

`string(39) "2d1d54rt5h4th5rh5tr1h%$&amp;^/+=gdgdfgd"`

I can only guess that you are printing your comparison on the web instead than on the terminal, and that you are presenting the result as rendered by the browser (and not the actual result), hence not seeing those extra four characters.

Before saving your data you should probably run something to decode the html entities in your input. Or you could do it before comparing, but much better to save the data properly.

```
$decrypted_key       = htmlspecialchars_decode($decrypted_key);
$order_decrypted_key = htmlspecialchars_decode($order_decrypted_key);
```